# Rebranch a branch that was previously merged

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

In the image below, whilst I was getting to grips with Git I made the following commits. Essentially I made a dev branch (pink), made some commits to it, switched back to my master branch (blue) and made some more commits before merging my dev branch into master.

What I'd like to do now is rebranch "dev" so I can work on a new feature. Git isn't allowing me to make a new branch "dev" as it has previously existed. I'm aware I could make a new "foo" branch but I'd like to keep the total number of branches down if I can. Is there a way have dev updated to the latest commit and rebranch it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the cleanest way to continue is to merge code back from your master to your "dev" branch. This way you will get all the changes from your master branch into your "dev" branch.

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin master
git push origin dev
```

Assuming you have the dev branch locally already (if not run `git checkout -b dev --track origin/dev`) and assuming that your remote is called origin, this should checkout the dev branch, then fetch and merge in changes from the remote master branch, then push back up to the remote dev branch.

This will also prevent any issues with force pushing or deleting the branch and then recreating.

Comment: Seems like the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Since there is already a remote branch `dev` you should create a new branch and leave the dev as it its.

If you really want to change the existent remote branch `dev` you can either delete the `dev` branch locally and remotely and create a new `dev` branch or you can reset the `dev` branch to point to another commit and push it.

**Keep in mind** that in both cases you change the `origin/dev` commit pointer. In other words the remote branch will point to another commit. If other developers are working on the `dev` branch they will be in big trouble when they pull the next time. If they already pushed their changes in the meanwhile you effectively deleting their changes.

So if there are others working on `dev` you should first discuss it with them.
I you can't be sure that you are the only one who works on the `dev` than don't do it.

Nevertheless if you want to do it or you really have to here is how it works:

**Reset dev to master and push --force**

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard master
git push --force origin dev
```

**Delete local and remote dev and re-create**

```
git checkout master // ensure you are not on dev
git branch -D dev
git push origin :dev
git checkout -b dev master
git push -u origin dev
```

Comment: You don't have to force the push in your first version. It's a simple fast-forward. You could also do `git checkout master; git merge --ff-only dev`.

Comment: @musiKk Yes that's right as long as the remote pointer has not been modified (push by other developers) in the meanwhile. So I keep the first version as it is, but a good comment.  Thanks.

Comment: If other developers already base work on the branch, you are effectively deleting their efforts. This is even worse!

Comment: @musiKk Yes I updated the answer in order to make the problems with this approach more clear.